# C++ Boost multithreading strange behavior

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, operators

I am following Boost multithreading tutorial [here](https://www.quantnet.com/threads/c-multithreading-in-boost.10028/)
.  The code is as follow:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

class CallableClass
{
private:
    // Number of iterations
    int m_iterations;

public:

    // Default constructor
    CallableClass()
    {
        m_iterations = 10;
    }

    // Constructor with number of iterations
    CallableClass(int iterations)
    {
        m_iterations = iterations;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    CallableClass(const CallableClass& source)
    {
        m_iterations = source.m_iterations;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~CallableClass()
    {
        cout << "Callable class exiting." << endl;
    }

    // Assignment operator
    CallableClass& operator = (const CallableClass& source)
    {
        m_iterations = source.m_iterations;
        return *this;
    }

    // Static function called by thread
    static void StaticFunction()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  // Hard-coded upper limit
        {
            cout << i << " - Do something in parallel (Static function)." << endl;
            boost::this_thread::yield(); // 'yield' discussed in section 18.6
        }
    }

    // Operator() called by the thread
    void operator () ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_iterations; i++)
        {
            cout << i << " - Do something in parallel (operator() )." << endl;
            boost::this_thread::yield(); // 'yield' discussed in section 18.6
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    boost::thread t(&CallableClass::StaticFunction);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << i << " - Do something in main method." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image]
However, if I change main() to this:

```
int main()
{
    // Using a callable object as thread function
    int numberIterations = 20;
    CallableClass c(numberIterations);
    boost::thread t(c);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << i << " - Do something in main method." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The class destructor is called before the operator is executed.  I don't quite understand this behavior.  Shouldn't the class stops executing when the destructor is called?  Also, why does the operator has two sets of brackets?  How do I know when the 2nd thread (not main()) stops and safely exits?  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No `boost::thread` doesn't stop executing when it is destructed. `std::thread` doesn't allow you to do this and will call `std::terminate` if you destruct the thread without joining it.

You need to add `t.join()` to the end of your main() method.

`void operator () ()` is the () operator with no parameters, the first () is the name of the operator, the second() is the list of parameters. For example a callable class with parameters would look like:

```
struct s
{
   void operator ()( int p ) {};
}
```

Comment: Does that mean it is a run away thread, eating up memory and CPU power?

Comment: probably not, it'll crash fairly quickly when the members of c that it is trying to use cease to exist. The process will normally terminate anyway when main returns

Comment: Before `t.join()` it would not hurt to use `t.joinable()`

Comment: wouldn't hurt but as the thread has been created earlier in the method it will always be joinable in this case as far as I know.

Comment: So how do I know when it terminates, knowing that the destructor does not indicate its termination?

Comment: by waiting for join to return

Comment: "CaTx, you can use simple flag like `std::atomic<bool> is_terminated{false};` and set it `true` inside your `thread` after it terminates/raise an exception/ finished. Whatever you handle, that corresponding to the thread termination.